# Scientific Researcher German Visa

Tags: germany

I have been offered a research position in Germany and applied for the scientific researcher visa. Can someone let me know the normal duration for the approval of the visa?

Comment: What research have you done already? Doesn't the consulate provide any information about visa processing times?

Comment: This information is not available on the German embassy website in Italy.

Comment: I have found it, got forwarded from Napoli consulate web page (hk-diplo.de): https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/visabestimmungen-node#content_5